# For each $\alpha \gt 0,$ find all pairs $(x_0,y_0) \in \Bbb R^2$ such that the given IVP has a unique solution in the neighbourhood of $(x_0,y_0).$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

> For each $\alpha \gt 0,$ find all pairs of $\left (x_0,y_0 \right ) \in \Bbb R^2$ such that the following initial value problem has a unique solution in the neighbourhood of $\left (x_0,y_0 \right )$ $$y' = y^{\alpha}\ ;\ y \left (x_0 \right ) = y_0.$$

How do I proceed? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks for your valuable time for reading.

Comment: Use the [Existence and Uniqueness Theorems](http://home.iitk.ac.in/~sghorai/TEACHING/MTH203/ode5.pdf) for first order ODE to start.

Comment: So for all $\alpha \gt 0,$ we could have taken $x_0 = 0$ and $y_0 = 2.$ Then both $y^{\alpha}$ and $y^{{\alpha} - 1}$ $\left ( = \dfrac {\partial} {{\partial} y} \left (y^{\alpha} \right ) \right )$ are continuous in the rectangular (or square) region $$R = \left \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2\ \bigg |\ |x| \leq 1,\, |y - 2| \leq 1 \right \}.$$ Then the given IVP has a unique solution in the $\delta$-neighbourhood of $(0,2),$ where $$\delta = \min \left \{1, \dfrac {1} {3^{\alpha}} \right \} = \dfrac {1} {3^{\alpha}}.$$ Am I right @Shubham Johri? Thanks.

Comment: So in general we could have taken $y_0 \in \Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$  and $x_0 \in \Bbb R.$ That will suffice. That means $(x_0,y_0) \in \Bbb R \times \left ( \Bbb R \setminus \{0 \} \right ) = \Bbb R^2 \setminus$ real line.